# Prove there is only one solution to the Diophantine equation $p^n - p = q^m - q$ where $p$ and $q$ are odd primes $p\gt q$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, open-problem

Consider numbers of the form $p^n - p$ where $p>2$ is a prime and $n>1 \in \mathbb{Z}$. How many of these have a unique representation? $2184$ can be written in this form $2$ ways, $3^7-3, 13^3-13$, can any other numbers?

The OEIS sequence entry [A057896](https://oeis.org/A057896) consists of numbers which can be expressed $m^k-m$ more than one way. The number $2184$ is the only one listed which has $m$ prime for both solutions and a computational bound of $10^{24}$ is given under which no other solutions have been found. The related sequence [A308324](https://oeis.org/A308324) is a subsequence of A057896 which allows only prime $m$.

The question is closely related to the the Pillai Conjecture since uniqueness would imply there are no other solutions (except $3,13$) to the Diophantine Equation $p^n - q^m = p - q$. In 2001 Bennett showed that for fixed p and q this equation has at most two solutions (no triple representations) and further conjectured that the general equation (allowing $p$ and $q$ to be composite) has only the 8 solutions which he presents. For only one of those solutions $(3,13)$ is $p$ and $q$ both prime.

If the conjecture made by Bennett is correct this is the only solution to this equation. See his paper [On Some Exponential Equations of
S. S. Pillai](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/B-CJM-Pillai.pdf) for more details.

Comment: I know Pillai's conjecture, but don't we have infinite many possible values of $p-q$ ? Neverhteless, it seems to be true that $2184$ is the only example with more than one representation. I created a vector with all combinations wih $3\le p\le 10^4$ , $2\le n\le 50$ and there was no other duplicate.

Comment: Neither did the range $3\le p\le 1000$ , $2\le n\le 100$ give another duplicate.

Comment: I'm guessing you know that it is  for odd n divisible by lcm(p-1,p+1) by polynomial remainder theorem ? and p-1 for all n

Comment: See discussion by FredH in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159173/find-all-positive-integer-a-b-such-that-a3-b7-a-b/3159378#comment6506130_3159378)

Comment: I wanted to cross reference this thread: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/158071

Answer (score 1):

**More Progress**

This idea is an attempt to generalize the proof of a [special case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1947650/find-positive-integer-x-y-such-that-7x-3y-4?rq=1) by @starfall. This approach does not imply there exists a solution if the following two cases don't hold. It only provides some cases where solutions cannot exist.

*Case 1*

Let $k=ord_p q$ and $c=(q^{k}-1)/p$.

If $c\equiv 0 \pmod p$ then a solution cannot exist since $p(p^{n-1}-1)=q(q^{m-1}-1)$ implies p divides $(q^{m-1}-1)$ only once.

An example for this case is $(p,q,k,c)=(11,3,5,22)$.

If we apply the same logic symmetrically, swapping p for q we have the examples $$\{(17,3,2,96),(7,5,4,480),(19,3,1,6),(19,7,6,6720840),(19,13,12,170254993774320)\}.$$

*Case 2*

Further, if we let $j=ord_c p$ there can also be no solution if $p^j \equiv 1 \pmod {q^2}$ since q can divide $p^{n-1}-1$ only once. Some examples of this case are:

$$(p,q,k,c,j)=
\{(7,3,6,104,12)
,(11,5,5,284,70)
,(13,7,12,1064714400,2520)
,(17,3,16,2532160,960)
,(19,3,18,20390552,756)
,(19,5,9,102796,4140)
,(19,13,18,5918705629050389112,104628420)
,(19,17,9,6241467184,21601152)\}$$

Applying the same logic symmetrically we have the example $(17,13,6,1856736,1224).$

Instead of c we can also use the squarefree part of c and arrive at the same result.

Considering these two cases for $3\le q<p\le 19$ only leaves the possible solutions: $$(p,q)=\{(5,3),(11,7),(13,3),(13,5),(13,11),(17,5),(17,7),(17,11),(19,11)\}.$$

Regardless, there do not seem to be any solutions for $3\le q<p\le 19$ for $n \lt 10^9$ using a search based on the fact that $m=floor(n \ln(p)/\ln(q))$ and naive [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation). This is consistent with Theorem 1.5 from Bennett which states there can be no additional solutions for $p-q \le 100$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a for solution n = 3 and m = (6k+1) for a positive integer k.

(1) ... $p^3-p=q^{6k+1}-q$ can be factored as

(2) ... $p(p-1)(p+1) = q(q^k-1)(q^k+1)(q^{2k}-q^k+q)(q^{2k}+q^k+1)$

From (1) we can get (3) ... $p^3 > q^{6k+1}$ which would also imply $p > q^{2k}$

From (2) we can see that p must divide either $(q^{2k}-q^k+q)$ or $(q^{2k}+q^k+1)$

That would mean that (4) ... $p \le (q^{2k}+q^k+1)$.

Combining (3) and (4) we get: $q^{6k+1} < p^3 \le (q^{2k}+q^k+1)^3$

Which would imply: $q^{6k+1} < (q^{2k}+q^k+1)^3$

The only solution to this inequality is $q = 3, k=1$. We could do induction on both $q$ and $k$ to show this but it gets unwieldy

This method would work for other Superior highly composite numbers for m. ex. $m = 12k+1$.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to generalize it.